# Create recursive call in macro function

Tags: elixir

I try to create a pipe **>>>** that run every function again in case of failure.

Working version without macros:

```rb
defmodule Retry.Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import RetryPipe

  setup_all do

    %{a: 1, b: 2}

  end

  test "example", details do

    retry_function(fn -> func1(details) end, 2)
    |> (&(retry_function(fn -> func2(&1) end, 2))).()
    |> (&(retry_function(fn -> func3(&1) end, 2))).()
    |> (&(retry_function(fn -> func4(&1) end, 2))).()

  end

  def retry_function(fun_to_retrieve, 1) do
    fun_to_retrieve.()
  end
  def retry_function(fun_to_retrieve, loops) do
    try do
      fun_to_retrieve.()
    rescue
      msg -> IO.inspect(msg)
        retry_function(fun_to_retrieve, loops-1)
    end
  end

  def func1(details) do
    IO.inspect("func1")
    assert details.a == 1
    details
  end

  def func2(details) do
    IO.inspect("func2")
    assert details.b == 2
    details
  end

  def func3(details) do
    IO.inspect("func3")
    raise "failure"
  end

  def func4(details) do
    IO.inspect("func4")
  end
end
```

I got the expected result:

But when I try to implement it with macro like this:

```rb
defmodule RetryPipe do
  defmacro left >>> right,
    do: retry(left, right, 2)

  def retry(param, func, 1),
    do: quote do: unquote(param) |> unquote(func)

  def retry_function(param, func, loops) do
    quote  do
      try do

        unquote(param) |> unquote(func)

      rescue

        msg -> IO.inspect(msg)
               retry_function(param, func, loops-1)

      end
    end
  end
end
```

I try to call from the Macro function a recursive function: **retry_function** that supposed to run again in case pf failure in the function (by changing the third parameter I can control how many times it will retry before it actually fail)

And then I use it like this:

```rb
defmodule Retry.Test do
  use ExUnit.Case
  import RetryPipe

  setup_all do

    %{a: 1, b: 2}

  end

  test "example", details do

    details
    >>> func1()
    >>> func2()
    >>> func3()
    >>> func4()

  end

  def func1(details) do
    IO.inspect("func1")
    assert details.a == 1
    details
  end

  def func2(details) do
    IO.inspect("func2")
    assert details.b == 2
    details
  end

  def func3(details) do
    IO.inspect("func3")
    raise "failure"
  end

  def func4(details) do
    IO.inspect("func4")
  end
end
```

I expected to get in the result:

```rb
Automation.CICDTests.EndToEnd.Test
  * test example
"func1"
"func2"
"func3"
%RuntimeError{message: "failure"}
"func3"
  * test example
 (7.2ms)

  1) test example
 (Automation.CICDTests.EndToEnd.Test)
     test/cicd_tests/end_to_end_test.exs:17
     ** (RuntimeError) failure
     stacktrace:
       test/cicd_tests/end_to_end_test.exs:40: Automation.CICDTests.EndToEnd.Test.func3/1



Finished in 0.1 seconds
1 test, 1 failure

Randomized with seed 0
```

But instead I got:

```rb
Automation.CICDTests.EndToEnd.Test
  * test example
"func1"
"func2"
"func3"
%RuntimeError{message: "failure"}
"func1"
"func2"
"func3"
%RuntimeError{message: "failure"}
"func1"
"func2"
"func3"
%RuntimeError{message: "failure"}
"func1"
"func2"
"func3"
  * test example
 (7.2ms)

  1) test example
 (Automation.CICDTests.EndToEnd.Test)
     test/cicd_tests/end_to_end_test.exs:17
     ** (RuntimeError) failure
     stacktrace:
       test/cicd_tests/end_to_end_test.exs:40: Automation.CICDTests.EndToEnd.Test.func3/1



Finished in 0.1 seconds
1 test, 1 failure

Randomized with seed 0
```

Comment: Perhaps you should first try to get a working version without macros - and then transform it into macros once it's fully tested..

Comment: How can I do it without macro?

Comment: first define the function `left_right` that you want `>>>` to replace. Put the _(working) code in your question then others may know more easily what you want.

Comment: I did it and added working version without macros

Answer (score 0):

The main issue is once the retries exhausted, one should retry if and only if it was within the owner of the call, not the induced error down the pipe.

That said, one must explicitly invalidate the `__STACKTRACE__` and retry if the `func` passed was actually the function which raised. The code below demonstrates the possible approach.

Also, it’s essential to unquote the subsequent call to `retry/3`, I am curious how the version you posted had ever compiled since you returned the `retry` content quoted twice.

```rb
defmodule RetryPipe do
  defmacro left >>> right,
    do: retry(left, right, 2)

  def retry(param, func, 1),
    do: quote do: unquote(param) |> unquote(func)

  def retry(param, func, loops) do
    {m, f} =
      case func do
        {{:., _, [{:__aliases__, _, [mod]}, fun]}, _, _} ->
          {Module.concat([mod]), fun}
        _ ->
          {nil, nil}
      end

    quote do
      try do
        unquote(param) |> unquote(func)
      rescue
        ex ->
          case __STACKTRACE__ do
            [{unquote(m), unquote(f), _arity, _meta} | _] ->
              unquote(retry(param, func, loops - 1))
            _ -> reraise ex, __STACKTRACE__
          end
      end
    end 
  end
end
```

The test would look like below.

```rb
defmodule Test do
  def f1(details),
    do: IO.inspect(details, label: "OK[1]")

  def f2(details) do
    IO.inspect(details, label: "BAD[2]")
    raise "failure"
  end

  def f3(details),
    do: IO.inspect(details, label: "OK[3]")
end

import RetryPipe
%{a: 1, b: 2} >>> Test.f1() >>> Test.f2() >>> Test.f3()

#⇒ OK[1]: %{a: 1, b: 2}
#⇒ BAD[2]: %{a: 1, b: 2}
#
# ** (RuntimeError) failure
#    iex:35: Test.f2/1
```

Please note, that this code might require additional tweaking when dealing with local functions, and it is in general extremely fragile. `__STACKTRACE__` was not invented for that, after all.

---

If you want to retry several times, just do it explicitly. Pipes might look sexy, but usually, they are not something your fellow developers would like to see in unfamiliar code.

Comment: your suggestion didn't pass compilation on my computer... but anyway it didn't solve my issue because I want it to work for every case and every numbers of loops.

Comment: Try to upgrade [tag:elixir], that’s all I could suggest without ever knowing what compilation error you get back. In any case, I had by no mean an intent to _solve your issue_, I explained why you see what you see in the test (several outputs.) The main message of my answer would be **don’t do that, because it is counter-idiomatic and absolutely not maintainable.**

Comment: I added now to the question working version without macros and as you can see it's very ugly, unreadable and very hard to maintainable.
this is the reason that I try to use macro.